# How to send a POST request with curl, using chrome's Copy as cURL (cmd) feature?

Tags: batch-file, curl, post

I get a request via chrome F12 => Network. I click on the RMB request, click Copy => Copy as cURL (cmd). I get something like this:

```
curl 'https://account.mail.ru/api/v1/user/signup' \
  -H 'authority: account.mail.ru' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'x-request-id: ef1e213c-26a6-332d-bf1b-8be1a971f6fe' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'origin: https://account.mail.ru' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru&app_id_mytracker=58519' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie:' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="extended"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="more_password_strength"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="context"\r\n\r\nsignup\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="browser"\r\n\r\n{"screen":{"availWidth":"1920","availHeight":"1040","width":"1920","height":"1080","colorDepth":"24","pixelDepth":"24","availLeft":"0","availTop":"0"},"navigator":{"vendorSub":"","productSub":"20030107","vendor":"Google Inc.","maxTouchPoints":"0","doNotTrack":"inaccessible","hardwareConcurrency":"8","cookieEnabled":"true","appCodeName":"Mozilla","appName":"Netscape","appVersion":"5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36","platform":"Win32","product":"Gecko","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36","language":"ru-RU","onLine":"true","webdriver":"false","pdfViewerEnabled":"true","deviceMemory":"8"},"flash":{"version":"inaccessible"}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="from"\r\n\r\nmain\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads_common"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\n{"first":"imechko","last":"famochka"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="birthday"\r\n\r\n{"day":3,"month":6,"year":1992}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sex"\r\n\r\nfemale\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="login"\r\n\r\nfamochka\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="domain"\r\n\r\ninbox.ru\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\n111zzz111zzz=\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="restore"\r\n\r\n{"secret":"-","secret_answer":"-","additional_email":"ardacan54524@gmail.com"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="htmlencoded"\r\n\r\nfalse\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="utm"\r\n\r\n{}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

But it does not work if you write this code in start.bat, save it in the same directory as curl.exe and run start.bat. Bat starts to execute this code line by line. What is the correct way to use this code with cURL?

Comment: try to replace the quotes with double quotes and remove new lines and slashes - they do not work on windows.

Comment: That looks like the syntax Chrome uses when you click "Copy as cURL (bash)", not "Copy as cURL (cmd)"

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *»it does not work«*? Not a solution, but do in general not use the file name `start.bat` since there is also an internal command `start`…

Answer (score 0):

copy as **PowerShell** (Windows) instead of **curl**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).